# Recursive sum of subsets

Tags: c++, recursion, subset-sum

I have read through some other discussions, but cannot figure how to fix my program. As it recurses, my index counter eventually gets too large and promising does not work since it is out of bounds (or at least I believe this to be correct).  How can I fix this such that index never gets too large?

```
vector<uint> w;                // vector of weights
vector<bool> include;
uint W;                        // the desired weight
uint index = 0;
uint weight = 0;               // the current weight of subsets
uint total = 0;                // superset total

void sum_of_subsets( uint index,
                     uint weight,
                     uint total,
                     vector<bool> &include,
                     vector<uint> &w,
                     uint W )
{
    if( promising(index, weight, W, w, total) )
    {
        if( weight == W )
        {
            for( uint k = 0; k <= include.size(); k++ )
            {
                if(include.at(k))
                    cout << w.at(k) << " ";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            include.at(index + 1) = 1;
            sum_of_subsets( index + 1, 
                            weight + w.at(index + 1 ), 
                            total - w.at(index + 1),
                            include, w, W ) ;
            include.at(index + 1) = 0;
            sum_of_subsets( index + 1, 
                            weight, 
                            total - w.at(index + 1),
                            include, w, W );
        }
    }
}

bool promising ( uint index, 
                 uint weight, 
                 uint W, 
                 vector<uint> w,
                 uint total )
{
    return ( weight + total >= W )
            && ((weight == W) || (weight + w.at(index+1) <= W));
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what is it doing?

Comment: This is a sum of subsets problem that finds all sets that add up to the desired sum, W.  It is giving me an error:      

 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector<bool>::_M_range_check

Comment: I don't see any checks that limit 'index'.

Comment: I have put them before the recursive call and as the first line to promising.  Neither of them have seemed to work.  Do you have any suggestions?